# Registering the user from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

each `User` can only have one `MedicalHistory` so I have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_authentic
end

class MedicalHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Using the above I can successfully create the user from the `MedicalHistory` model in the console:

```
newuser = Medicalhistory.new
newuser.user = User.new
newuser.user.username='testusername'
newuser.user.password='blahblah'
newuser.user.password_confirmation='blahblah'
newuser.user.save
```

MedicalHistory Side looks like following

```
#controller
def new
    @medicalhistory = MedicalHistory.new
    @medicalhistory.user = User.new
end

#form
<%=...%>
<%=f.intput :cell_phone%>
<%=f.fields_for :user do |builder|%>
  <%= render "registration_form", :f => builder %>
<% end %>

#Partial
<%=f.input :email%>
<%=f.input :password%>
<%=f.input :password_confirmation%>
```

**Error**

When submitting the form I am getting below error:

```
User(#-) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#)
```

Error is on following line:

```
#controller
def create
    @medicalhistory = Medicalhistory.new(session[:medicalhistory_params]) #gives error
    #somewhere here I should extract registration fields and register the user
end
```

**Question**
Is there a way I can avoid fields in the partial (registration fields) getting into the `session[:medicalhistory_params]`...is there a `except` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your model as follows:

```
class MedicalHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

Ref here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using something like `params[:medical_history]` in `#create`?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look into accepts_nested_attributes_for

See this for an intro
http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes